# Is there a way to use :first in javascript queryselector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have a table containing a list of users and I would like to hide all their duplicates on an event. an example in the image below is hiding the second tr#user-3.

[image]

But when I tried using `temp1.querySelectorAll('tr:not(#user-3:first)')` it didn't return any node instead and it brings invalid selector error. What could be the cause and how do I solve it ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you mean [**:first-of-type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) or [**:first-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:first is not part of the CSS spec, this is jQuery specific.

To access the first and last elements, try.

```
    var nodes = temp1.querySelectorAll('tr');
    var first = nodes[0];
    var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
```

Comment: I want to be able to get all nodes apart form the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector()` instead. It always gets you the first element that matches the selector.

```
const firstEl = temp1.querySelector('tr');
```

[QuerySelector Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: I want to get all that are not first elements not just one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what was the issue for the given problem. However the code below seems to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tables">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="user3">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="user3">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="user3">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var table = document.querySelectorAll(".tables tr#user3:not(:nth-child(2))");
        //console.log(table);
        table.forEach(el => {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        })
    }
</script>
</html>
```

The code also works with `last-child`